# trying put search bar in android in my listview

Tags: java, android

**I was trying put a search bar in my listview when this happend**
*Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
*

```
protected   EditText editText=findViewById(R.id.Edittext);
>in my oncreate i create a editText how will search for that

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       filter(s.toString());
    }
});
> my class to filter how will filter the results 
private void filter(String text){
    for (Model item:mList){
        if (item.getNome().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))){
            mList.add(item);
        }
    }
    mAdapter.filterList(mList);
}
>In my  class Adapater below "getcount()"
public void filterList(ArrayList<Model>mList){
recordList=mList;
notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of weeks ago. Due to the limited code above, I cannot go into details or tweak your code. But I suspect that the issue is that you are declaring two Adapter objects in the same class (whichever class the code snippet you provided belongs to). Try and tweak your code so this class only utilizes ONLY ONE Adapter object. Run it and it should get rid of the NullPointerException error. If you need more help, post more of the code above including where you created instances of your Adapter.